# How to export a Power Center mapping to SQL statements?

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

Is it always possible to export an Informatica PowerCenter mapping to a sequence of SQL statements? How would we do it? Plus points if we can do it programmatically.

My mapping is from a relational database to another relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Informatica actually makes it possible to convert the whole mapping to a INSERT-SELECT statement, as long as some conditions are met.

- Most importantly: Pushdown Optimization option must be available (AFAIR it is licenced separately, hence not always available)
- Session property `Pushdow Optimization` needs to be set to `Full`

Then `Pushdown Optimization Viewer` ([more info](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/advanced-workflow-guide/pushdown-optimization/configuring-sessions-for-pushdown-optimization/viewing-pushdown-groups.html)) allows you to take a sneak peek at the query being a result of complete mapping transformation into SQL statement.

NOTE: This may also require enabling `Allow Temporary View for Pushdown`.

NOTE2: This feature has a number of limitations (eg. it's not possible when local variables are used, etc.).

Comment: Nice. Limitations of Push Down Optimization: https://thinketl.com/pushdown-optimization-in-informatica-cloud-iics/#4_Limitations_of_Pushdown_Optimization

Answer (score 1):

No, currently Infa doesn't give any option to convert a infa mapping to a SQL programmatically (else who will use informatica :D ).
If you want to write a SQL for a mapping then you need to write something using some programming language - you can but it will be difficult. Sometime it may be impossible if it involves multiple DBs, files, XML/http transform, complex logic etc.

Here is some guidance for simple 1-1 mapping consists of 1 or multiple sources from same DB, expression, lookup tr, and one target -

```
SQ1 -->|
       |--> EXP--> TGT
SQ2 -->|--> LKP--> |
```

1. use the metadata tables to find out source to target mappings SQL. You need to go to widget level to find out exact logic.
2. get LOOKUP table info as well.
3. get source names. To fetch from source, you can use select statement (use join if needed).
4. get target names. To load data into target, you need to write insert into.

Your whole SQL should look like this

```
insert into 
<<get the table from step4>>
SELECT
<<get the expression logic from step 1 >>
FROM 
<<get source/sources from step 3>>
LEFT JOIN <<get lookup table and join condition from step 2>>
```

Again, the mapping can be really complex and sometime even simple tweak can throw your program off. I recommend, analyze the complexity before investing time on this.
Here is a mapping analyzer tool you can use to analyze (created by a SO user i respect).
https://xmlanalyzer.maciejg.pl/

Comment: Well, dear friend - it's actually possible :) And yet - Informatica is still useful! For a number of reasons: even though it's possible to generate SQL, it is by far easier to have a look at a graphical mapping then long set of SQL code. And if underlying DB will change, Informatica will generate code appropiately. And due to data lineage. And a few more reasons even! :)